# Why use recursive variables just for simple shell command names?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know the difference between simple and recursive variables in makefile.
I have seen many makefiles (including linux kernel) that use recursive variables for simple shell command names.
I think it's enough to use simple variables in that case.
But majority use recursive variables.
Are there any specific reasons to use recursive variables than simple ones?

```
CC = cc
AR = ar
RM = rm -f
DIFF = diff
TAR = tar
FIND = find
INSTALL = install
TCL_PATH = tclsh
TCLTK_PATH = wish
XGETTEXT = xgettext
MSGFMT = msgfmt
CURL_CONFIG = curl-config
PTHREAD_LIBS = -lpthread
```

Answer (score 1):

> are there any specific reasons to use recursive
>   variables than simple ones ?

Yes: simply-assigned variables are a GNU `make` extension.  Traditional `make` does not have that feature, and it is not specified by POSIX.  Therefore

1. Using ordinary ("recursive") assignment is more portable.  In fact, it is the only alternative available in some environments.
2. Using ordinary assignment is more traditional.
3. Using ordinary assignment is simply how many people learned to do it.
4. People who work primarily in environments whose default `make` is not GNU `make` may not even be aware / interested in simple assignment or other GNU extensions.

Additionally,

5. Using only one form of assignment throughout yields a makefile that is easier to understand, and ordinary assignment has some useful properties that may incline makefile authors to choose that variety.

There are probably others.

Comment: Note that even the GNU Autotools produce makefiles that eschew immediate assignment in favor of ordinary assignment, even though their authors and maintainers are well aware of GNU `make` and its features.  I'm confident that this is for portability purposes, since the Autotools strive to minimize the (substantial) need for adaptation to the build environment by using portable code and constructs.

Comment: Just for completeness, the latest POSIX standard will provide a simply-expanded variable variation, using the operator `::=` since `:=` was already used for other things in traditional SunOS make.  However, since this is a brand new capability it still has portability issues.

Comment: I didn't know that, @MadScientist.  For future reference, the latest released version of POSIX as of the time of this writing is the 2018 edition, and [this edition's `make` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) does not describe a `::=` (or `:=`) macro definition operator.

Comment: I'm not sure why not.  The request was accepted in 2011.  See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=330  Note that `:=` is not part of the standard: it could not be used since it already has long histories in two competing versions of make.

Comment: I see that, @MadScientist.  Perhaps the online docs were missed when the change was applied, or perhaps it was accepted but never actually applied at all.  If you have or are interested in creating a login at the Austin Group's bug tracker then it might be worthwhile raising a new issue there.  If in fact the change has not been applied at all, then notwithstanding the record of its acceptance, it is not (yet) in POSIX.

Comment: I do have a login but I would probably just email the mailing list.  Indeed it's not officially part of the standard.  However it is implemented in many versions of make in anticipation of the standard, and that's what's important :).

Comment: @mug896 I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  Who are "they"?  What are the "other places"?

Comment: @MadScientist I means in linux kernel Makefile there are also places using simple variables.  if using recursive variables is for portability reasons why they also use simple variables in other places as well ?

Comment: @mug896 The Linux kernel makefiles are not intended to be portable: they are specifically written to work with GNU make and only with GNU make.  They use a huge number of GNU make-specific features: simple variables are very _least_ of these.  This question is not in any way related to Linux kernel makefiles so I'm not sure why this subject has come up.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for comment. I'm just can't understand why they use recursive variables where it's enough to use simple variables

Comment: @mug896 If what you're asking is what is the advantage to using recursive variables (why not just ask that?), they are very useful because the order in which you define them doesn't matter.  The value (right-hand side) can contain references to variables that won't be defined until later in the makefile, or even not until recipes are being run (e.g., automatic variables such as `$@` or `$*` etc.)  Some people think makefiles should always use recursive variables for flexibility unless there's a specific reason simple variables are required.